# someone deposit money on my credit card

Tags: money-transfer, fraud

someone activated my new credit card while I was still using the old one. the same day they deposit 980 dollars in my credit card, they didnt have a chance to use it because I blocked right away both card the new one and the old one. today I receive another deposit of 1200 dollars, I'm.not using that money but I'm worry that mistake could be some sort of scam or illegal activity.  I do have the new credit card they are not spending any money they just keep deposit money on it now I have a negative number on my credit card. what should I do?

Comment: There are no free lunches and credit card companies don't give away money unannounced.  Contact them for clarification.

Answer (score 7):

The usual scam is to transfer you money by some means, then contact you and explain they made a mistake and to please return it.

Only the original money is stolen somehow and eventually that will be figured out and it will be taken away.  The transfer from you to them is authorized, though, so it's not undone.

I haven't heard of it happening with credit cards but I don't see a reason it couldn't.

Comment: I agree that the OP should resolve this by being defensive. Resolve it through the bank. Do not under any circumstances send money directly to a third party, thus bypassing the bank, to resolve the problem. And given the snafu I'd get a new credit card number from the bank.